# Auto expand background color of div with its content

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and inside that I have three paragraphs.
And the parent `div` has background color set.
I want to expand the `height` of parent `div` vertically when the paragraphs content increases.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cart-item"> 
    <p class="item-name">We will reinforce some test dat some test data</p>  
    <p class="item-price">25.87</p>
    <p><input type="text" id="txtCount" maxlength="2" class="prod-qty" name="quantity" value="1"></p>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cart-item {
    line-height: 30px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0.3em;
    /* background: #eeeeee; */
    /* border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; */
    color: #333333;
    background: #eeeeee repeat-y;
}

.cart-item p {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add:

```
.cart-item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or use clear fix:

```
.cart-item:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much,
But I want three Paragraphs to be one line inside div.
Regardless the length of first paragraph.
How to achieve this?